# Total cell count of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to get the total number of cells that are present in a datagridview.  This is then used to determine if I want to include the column header text when copying/pasting the data, I only want this displayed if all records are selected.

I am using the following code to get the total number of cells but is there a better way to get this value?

```
var totalCellCount = DataGridView2.ColumnCount * DataGridView2.RowCount;
```

I couldn't find a property that contained a count of all cells, maybe I am missing it.  Is there a better way to get the number of cells?

My datagridview has the `ClipboardCopyMode` set to `EnableWithAutoHeaderText`, but I want to set it to `EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText` when they select all rows/columns in the grid.  So I am using the total number of cells in the code below:

```
private void DataGridView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (m_RecordCount == 0)
     return;

      var totalCellCount = DataGridView2.ColumnCount * DataGridView2.RowCount;

      if (DataGridView2.SelectedCells.Count == totalCellCount)
      {
          if (e.KeyChar == (char)3)
          {
            DataGridView2.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
            var clipboardContent = this.DataGridView2.GetClipboardContent();

            if (clipboardContent != null)
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(clipboardContent.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text));
            }
            e.Handled = true;
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DataGrid.Items` property returns a `DataGridItemCollection` representing the `DataGridItems` in the DataGrid.

Each `DataGridItem` is representative of a single row in the rendered table. Also, the `DataGridItem` exposes a `Cells` property which represents the no. of tablecells (in other words, the columns) in the rendered table. From here if you need any other custom scenarios you will have to either add it to the original Question or code a solution

```
var rowCount = DataGridView2.Items.Count; //Number of Items...i.e. Rows;

// Get the no. of columns in the first row.
var colCount = DataGridView2.Items[0].Cells.Count;
```

if you want the total number of Rows also try

1. If you want to get at total items an you want a real total for example if you have multiple pages.. If so you shouldn't be trying to find that information from the GridView but instead look at the underlying DataSource that you bound your GridView.

Example ----

```
 List<SomeObject> lis = GetYourData();
 DataGrid.DataSource = list;
 DataGrid.DataBind();

 // if you want to get the count for a specific page
 int currentPage = 2;
 int countForPage2 = (list.Count > currentPage * totalItemsPerPage)) ?
     totalItemsPerPage : list.Count - ((currentPage - 1) * totalItemsPerPage);
```

Comment: But if I want the total number of cells, I still have to multiply the two numbers, correct?

Comment: do you have paging ..? if so then my answer will need to be expanded.. let me know so that I can append an additional option if you have multiple pages

Comment: I don't have paging.  I am using the total number of cells to determine if I should include the Column Header text, so if they paste the data into Excel they have the headers. I updated my OP with more details.

Comment: Your response is unclear.. how does total number of cells determine if they should have column Headers or not.. if rowcount > 0 then you should include column headers.. so what's the disconnect..?

Comment: the users only want the column headers if they copy the entire grid. Unfortunately it is their request.

Comment: then you want to check to the selectedItems Count.. this is a rather odd request but can still be done.

Comment: I agree it is an odd request.